# What is the taskArtifacts folder in my android projet inside my mercurial repository for?

Tags: android-studio, mercurial, repository, build.gradle, gitignore

So, I have an Android project created using Android Studio. I´m not so familiar with Android Studio yet, so I don´t know if this folder is created by the Android Studio or by Mercurial.

The folder path is :

```
Repo-> .gradle -> 2.2.1 ->taskArtifacts -> 

cache.properties
cache.properties.lock
fileHashes.bin
fileSnapshots.bin
outputFileStates.bin
taskArtifacts.bin
```

I want to commit just files that my teammates need, but I don´t know if I put this folder in the .gitignore if I will get an error later.

What does this folder do? What is it for?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should the .gradle folder be added to version control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200831/should-the-gradle-folder-be-added-to-version-control)

Comment: Take a look at [Mercurial .hgignore for Android Studio projects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311746/mercurial-hgignore-for-android-studio-projects)

Comment: Thank you for the support guys, but I want to know what is inside it. What it is for. Which configuration. I don´t want to know if I have to put in my repository.

Comment: The thread I posted as a duplicate answers exactly your question: it's basically a cache folder for Gradle. Read the answers for a more comprehensive explanation.

Comment: Well you certainly did ask whether you should or should not commit those files.

Comment: Are you using Mercurial or Git? You should learn your DVCS terminology. You ask what to put in `.gitignore` file, but Mercurial ignore file is `.hgignore`