# what are .gradle/version/... files on SourceTree

Tags: git, android-studio, atlassian-sourcetree

These files appear on SourceTree (probably on other git version controller) maybe because I have updated Android Gradle version before.
[image]
What are these files? These files seem like appearing on and on unless I commit it. What is the best way to deal with them? commit them as other regular commits?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200831/should-the-gradle-folder-be-added-to-version-control ; **TL;DR:** The entire `.gradle` directory should be excluded from your git repo, you can do that by adding `.gradle/` to your repo's `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Thanks! I will mark your answer if you post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [Should the .gradle folder be added to version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200831/should-the-gradle-folder-be-added-to-version-control)

> What are these files?

Gradle (i.e. your build system) creates files that are needed for managing your build process. I'm not a Gradle user (let alone any kind of Gradle expert) but from what I can tell from their documentation and support community Gradle determines what needs (re-)building based on file hashes - as well as keeping its own logs; so Gradle keeps track of those hashes and logs in the `.gradle` directory - which means those files are both ephemeral and specific to your machine, which means they should not be included in your `.git` repo (because source-control repos, generally, should not contain local build artefacts) <sub>(I would even go so-far as to suggest [you might want to reconfigure Gradle so it puts its files in your `TEMP` dir instead of your project directory tree](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-change-the-default-gradle-local-directory-user-home-gradle-to-other-directory-like-d-gradle/3946/2), but as I have zero experience with Gradle I don't know if that's actually a good idea or not)</sub>.

> What is the best way to deal with them?

You should delete the directory in your git repo (e.g. `git rm .gradle`), commit the deletion, then exclude them from your repo via `gitignore` and then commit the `.gitignore` change (in that order, otherwise the `git rm` step itself would be ignored).

You may-or-may-not want to also go-back-in-time to earlier commits so it would be like the directory was never added in the first place, but rewriting history in git is painful (and if you're on a team: should be avoided entirely) so that's up to you.